# oracle11g sql to find difference between rows from the same table

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle11g

I have a table **SAMPLE** having unique column(sal_id, gal_id) and amount, tax, date and some more columns.

**SAMPLE table**

```
 actual_id, sal_id, gal_id, processed_flag, amount, tax     date    
   1          101     201     Y             10       1     25-Aug-12  
   2          101     201     Y             20       3     27-Aug-12  
   3          101     201     N             15       2     29-Aug-12
```

Now I need to find the difference between unprocessed (process_flag='N') and proceed data  (process_flag='Y') having maximum date. I need to calculate difference between amount and tax for (sal_id + gal_id) combination.

So the query return should be like this:

In this example, Since for (101, 201), we are having 2 processed row and (actual_id 2 having maximum date. So need to find difference between actual_id 3 & actual_id 2 row.

```
actual_id,  sal_id,  gal_id, total_amount, total_tax  date    
    3          101     201    -5 (15-20)    -1 (2-3)   29-Aug-12
```

I am using Oracle 11g. Please help me.

Comment: what will you do with the amount? subtract unprocessed - process or vice versa? what do you mean sal_id + gal_id? combined both id? or its value of the reference table?

Comment: Need to calculate (unprocessed amount - processed amount) and (unprocessed tax - processed tax). Combining actual_id, sal_id, gal_id, date forming a Unique Id for SAMPLE table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT DISTINCT "sal_id" sid,"gal_id" gid,"processed_flag" pf, max("amount") over
(partition BY "sal_id","gal_id","processed_flag") am,
max("tax") over
(partition BY "sal_id","gal_id","processed_flag") tx,
           max("actual_id") over
(partition BY "sal_id","gal_id","processed_flag") aid,
           max("date") over
(partition BY "sal_id","gal_id","processed_flag") dt
FROM sample)
SELECT t1.aid, t1.sid, t1.gid, t1.am-t2.am, t1.tx-t2.tx, t1.dt FROM t t1 JOIN t t2 ON t1.sid=t2.sid AND t1.gid=t2.gid
WHERE t1.pf='N' AND t2.pf='Y';
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc505/11) is a fiddle

---

**UPDATE:** The previous answer assumes that max(date) also has the max(amount).
a much better solution can be:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT *
FROM sample s
WHERE s."date" = (SELECT max("date") FROM sample s_in
                WHERE s_in."sal_id" = s."sal_id"
                AND s_in."gal_id" = s."gal_id"
                AND s_in."processed_flag" = s."processed_flag"))
SELECT t1."actual_id", t1."sal_id", t1."gal_id", t1."amount"-t2."amount" total_amount, t1."tax"-t2."tax" total_tax, t1."date"
FROM t t1 JOIN t t2 ON t1."sal_id"=t2."sal_id" AND t1."gal_id"=t2."gal_id"
WHERE t1."processed_flag"='N' AND t2."processed_flag"='Y';
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc505/23) is the fiddle

Comment: Thanks @A.B.Cade. It is working the way I expected. Thanks a lot. How about performance of the query since we are using so many partitions?

Comment: Hi Cade.. I need actual_id also in the result query. I modified a query by just adding "actual_id" aaa.. but getting two rows in the result query. pls help me in modifying the query.

Comment: But you have the actual_id (aliased as aid). Here is the fiddle after aliasing the fields http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc505/15. BTW, comming to think abount it, my answer assumes that max(tax) will have the max(date) which might not be true ...

Comment: yes @Cade.. you are right.. It is not necessary that max(tax) will have max(date). In my example, I just gave it like that. Need to consider only max(date) only. Modified my table data for better understanding..

Comment: Great @Cade. This is what exactly I want. Can u explain me one part in the query.  

     SELECT *
FROM sample s
WHERE s."date" = (SELECT max("date") FROM sample s_in
                WHERE s_in."sal_id" = s."sal_id"
                AND s_in."gal_id" = s."gal_id"
                **AND s_in."processed_flag" = s."processed_flag"**) .. 

when we say both processed_flag equal, how it is returning both 1st (flag Y) & 3rd row(flag N).

Comment: The inline-view (`with` clause) finds the records with date equels to the max date for the same sal_id, gal_id and processed_flag (no matter what they are), so basically it gives always 2 records one for 'N' and one for 'Y' (for every sal_id and gal_id). In the query itself we join it twice - one for the 'Y's records and once for the 'N's records. The join condition is sal_id and gal_id.